# Space left in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The HTML of the website

```
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-md-3"><div class="float-left" style="background-color:grey;">
<h2 style="background-color:yellow;">Notifications</h2>
<div>You have a new follow </div>
<div>Your previous request was approved</div>
<div></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">Hiiiii</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output leaves a space as such on the left:

[image]

I have tried to replace the padding and tried various float options, but none of them seem to work. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.container` class, this is to create a centered container.

If you don't want this use `.container-fluid` class as [detailed in the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers):

> Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.

If you don't want to use a container, then don't use a container at all.

```css
.navbar-pink {
background-color: pink
}

.title-yellow {
background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-pink"> 
<h1> NAVBAR </h1>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h2 class="title-yellow">Notifications</h2>
      <div>You have a new follow </div>
      <div>Your previous request was approved</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">Hiiiii</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still does leave a small amount of space

Comment: Thanks, adding a padding of 0% to the left makes it work :)

Comment: edited my answer, if you want to absolutely remove everything don't use a container. Removing margin/padding is **not** recommended, it will most likely break other things. But great if you figured something out.

Answer (score 1):

If i got correctly, you are trying to remove spacing from this portion
[see the arrow in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip61b.png) 
If this is the case, you can simply use bootstrap's css class "container-fluid" instead of "container".

The "container" class leaves paddings/spaces to left and right  whereas,
the "container-fluid" class utilizes full width of the screen.

Here is the full code--

```html
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<head>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="float-left" style="background-color:grey;">
                    <h2 style="background-color:yellow;">Notifications</h2>
                    <div>You have a new follow </div>
                    <div>Your previous request was approved</div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">Hiiiii</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please note, i have used bootstrap cdn.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already used the answer given before yours and it seemed to work the same